# Robust inference of normal distributions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

Say we have a large sample from a Normal distribution with **unknown** mean and variance. Say we randomly "inject" into this sample noisy data points from an **unknown** distribution.

How can I **robustly** fit a Normal distribution to this sample and use it to detect those outliers?

E.g.

```
# 1000 N(0,1) points
mu, sigma = 0, 1
sample = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

# Random contamination every 10 points:
mu, sigma = 100, 1
sample[::10] = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)

# Robust estimation (?)
mu_estimate, sigma_estimate = robust_estimation(sample)
```

Does `scipy` or `statsmodels` have any methods that can help address this problem?

Comment: Do you know how many noisy data point there are? Or their relative portion?

Comment: Thanks @zaxliu I am interested in scenarios where one can and when one can't make a good guess

Comment: A fully unknown distribution (even which class it belongs) may be too hard. Do you have some specific scenario that can help narrow down the assumption space?

Comment: And a naive way is to EM. Each round you use the 'most likely' samples to estimate mu and sigma, then with them calculate the likelyhood of samples.